# Unity3D Ads Advertisement.IsReady() always being false on iOS

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm having an issue with Advertisement.IsReady() always being false on iOS in a Unity game. In the editor, I get the default screen that says "This screen would be your ads".
I've double checked the game id and both the game id in the editor and the dashboard match. I'm using the Unity services to integrate it.

```
 if (Advertisement.IsReady())
    {
        Advertisement.Show();
    }
```

**Update**

I finally got an Android build and the ads work fine but still not able to get working ads in iOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded from 5.5.0b9 to 5.5.0f3 and that seems to have fixed the issue. The ads are now displaying correctly.